# Error converting NVARCHAR to BIGINT when in SUBQUERY with WHERE clause after invalid records filtered

Tags: sql-server, subquery, cast

I have a table that has an NVARCHAR column that contains data that cannot be converted to BIGINT.  I'm well aware of that and have filtered it out using `ISNUMERIC(BB.NVARCHARCOL) = 1`.  Despite this, I still get an error when trying to query the data stating that `Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.`

The following works fine (no errors reported by SQL):

```
SELECT *
FROM myNormalTable AA INNER JOIN myBadTable BB ON BB.NVARCHARCOL = AA.MYBIGINTCOL
WHERE ISNUMERIC(BB.NVARCHARCOL) = 1
```

The following throws the error:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM myNormalTable AA INNER JOIN myBadTable BB ON BB.NVARCHARCOL = AA.MYBIGINTCOL
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(BB.NVARCHARCOL) = 1
    ) ZZ 
WHERE ZZ.MYBIGINTCOL = 1234
```

This variation also throws the error:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM myNormalTable AA INNER JOIN
        (SELECT CAST(NVARCHARCOL AS BIGINT) NVARCHARCOL FROM myBadTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(NVARCHARCOL) = 1) BB
      ON BB.NVARCHARCOL = AA.MYBIGINTCOL
    ) ZZ 
WHERE ZZ.MYBIGINTCOL = 1234
```

Keep in mind that this does not error and returns all the records successfully...

```
SELECT CAST(NVARCHARCOL AS BIGINT) NVARCHARCOL FROM myBadTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(NVARCHARCOL) = 1
```

I was able to find a solution, which was to convert my BIGINT to NVARCHAR in the subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM myNormalTable AA INNER JOIN myBadTable BB ON BB.NVARCHARCOL = CAST(AA.MYBIGINTCOL AS NVARCHAR)
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(BB.NVARCHARCOL) = 1
    ) ZZ 
WHERE ZZ.MYBIGINTCOL = 1234
```

If I insert the records into a temporary table:

```
SELECT CAST(NVARCHARCOL AS BIGINT) NVARCHARCOL INTO #TEMP FROM myBadTable WHERE ISNUMERIC(NVARCHARCOL) = 1
```

I can use that temporary table in a subquery successfully:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM myNormalTable AA INNER JOIN #TEMP BB ON BB.NVARCHARCOL = AA.MYBIGINTCOL
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(BB.NVARCHARCOL) = 1
    ) ZZ 
WHERE ZZ.MYBIGINTCOL = 1234
```

**What in the world is going on?  It seems like SQL refuses to use the subquery to get a smaller result set before running the outer query, it wants to use the whole table regardless of what I do.  SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition**

Comment: ISNUMERIC() has loooooots of problems: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/ISNUMERIC()/71512/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `try_cast()` instead.

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from myNormalTable AA
  inner join #TEMP BB on try_cast(BB.NVARCHARCOL as bigint) = AA.MYBIGINTCOL
  --where try_cast(BB.NVARCHARCOL as bigint) is not null /* not neccessary for inner join */
 ) ZZ
where ZZ.MYBIGINTCOL = 1234
```

In Sql Server 2012 and up: each of these will return `null` when the conversion fails instead of an error.

- [**`try_convert(datatype,val)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)
- [**`try_cast(val as datatype)`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx)
- [**`try_parse(val as datatype [using culture])`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

Comment: This works.  Pretty much equivalent to converting my BIGINT to NVARCHAR instead.  Do you know why SQL ignores the subquery which filters out bad tables and goes to the base table?

Comment: @Brad and SqlZim: I put a comment on the question, but it has to do with how the Query Optimizer sometimes rearranges a query during optimization.

Answer (score 4):

SqlZim already gave you a good method to avoid the error in [his answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167189/error-converting-nvarchar-to-bigint-when-in-subquery-with-where-clause-after-inv/167190#167190). However, in the question and in comments you seem curious as to why one query throws an error and the other does not. I am able to reproduce your issue:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE (ID BIGINT NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT TOP (1000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
FROM master..spt_values;

CREATE TABLE dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE (ID_NV NVARCHAR(10) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE WITH (TABLOCK)
SELECT TOP (999) CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS NVARCHAR(10))
FROM master..spt_values

UNION ALL

SELECT 'ZOLTAN';
```

This query works fine:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
INNER JOIN dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV ON BI.ID = NV.ID_NV
WHERE ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1;
```

This query throws an error:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
    INNER JOIN dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV ON BI.ID = NV.ID_NV
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1
) ZZ 
WHERE ZZ.ID = 500;
```

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 25
>
> Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint.

The SQL Server query optimizer can reorder elements of a query as it sees fit to try to find a query plan with a good enough estimated cost, as long as the changes do not affect the final results of the query. To illustrate the concept lets walk through one possible way the second query can be refactored. To be clear, this is not the actual step-by-step process that the query optimizer goes through for this example. Start with the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
    INNER JOIN dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV ON BI.ID = NV.ID_NV
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1
) ZZ 
WHERE ZZ.ID = 500;
```

Push down the predicate:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
    INNER JOIN dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV ON BI.ID = NV.ID_NV
    WHERE BI.ID = 500 AND ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1
) ZZ;
```

The derived table is no longer needed so get rid of that:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
INNER JOIN dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV ON BI.ID = NV.ID_NV
WHERE BI.ID = 500 AND ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1
```

We know that `BI.ID = NV.ID_NV` so we can apply the filter on `Z.ID` to `NV.ID_NV` as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
INNER JOIN dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV ON BI.ID = NV.ID_NV
WHERE BI.ID = 500 AND ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1 AND NV.ID_NV = 500
```

The join no longer needs to be implemented as `INNER JOIN` because we are filtering down to a single value for both join columns. We can rewrite as a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
    WHERE BI.ID = 500
) 
CROSS JOIN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1 AND NV.ID_NV = 500
);
```

If we look at the query plan for the second query we can tell that the end result is very similar to the final transformed query:

[image: transformed query]

Here is the text of the filter predicate for reference:

```
CONVERT_IMPLICIT(bigint,[SE_DB].[dbo].[X_NVARCHAR_TABLE].[ID_NV] as [NV].[ID_NV],0)=(500) 
AND isnumeric(CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(20),[SE_DB].[dbo].[X_NVARCHAR_TABLE].[ID_NV] as [NV].[ID_NV],0))=(1)
```

If SQL Server evaluates the `CONVERT_IMPLICIT` part of the predicate before the `isnumeric` part then we get an error.

As a general rule, avoid relying on implied order of operations when writing SQL queries. You may have a query that works well today but starts to throw errors if data is added to the table or if a different query plan is chosen. There are, of course, exceptions (kind of). In practice, you will usually see the different parts of a `CASE` statement to evaluate in the order that you've written them, but even then it's possible to get [errors that you weren't expecting](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/06/t-sql-queries/dirty-secrets-of-the-case-expression). You can also add a superfluous `TOP` to parts of your query to encourage a certain order of operations. Consider the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP (9223372036854775807) *
    FROM dbo.X_BIGINT_TABLE BI 
    INNER JOIN dbo.X_NVARCHAR_TABLE NV ON BI.ID = NV.ID_NV
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(NV.ID_NV) = 1
    ) ZZ 
WHERE ZZ.ID = 500;
```

You and I know that the `TOP` will not change the results of the query, However, there is not a guarantee to the optimizer that the derived table won't return more than 9223372036854775807 rows so it must evaluate the `TOP`. Technically, in that query we ask for the first 9223372036854775807 rows and then we want to filter out rows with an `ID` different from 500. Pushing the `ID = 500` predicate down to the derived table could change the results so SQL Server will not do that. In this example, the query executes without an error and the filtering is done at the very end:

[image: top plan]